# read newline from scanf

Tags: c++, newline, scanf

I am trying to take input from stdin, using scanf line by line, but i need to execute a particular function when only a newline character is entered. Scanf doesnt seem to be doing this properly, and i cannot use fgets as the rest of program seems to stop working. Help?

```
char input[1000];
scanf("%s", input);

if((strcmp(input, "\n") == 0) {
// some code
}
```

doesnt seem to work.
I only need to implement this when there is only a newline character and nothing else. Thanks

Comment: `scanf` consumes whitespace, so yes, this won't work. What's wrong with using `fgets`? Can you tell us exactly why this isn't an option? Alternatively you could use `getchar` and read your input character by character - this'll let you detect `\n` but is otherwise less convenient.

Comment: Why not use actual C++ and use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: `scanf()` eats up the newline character, it's not part of the result.

Comment: You should try [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: @PaoloM & _@NathanOliver_ Same problem with `getline()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `std::string foo;
 std::getline(std::cin, foo);
 if (foo.empty())
  std::cout << "you didn't enter anything";` if you just press enter it will print that you didn't enter anything.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In a single character variable it can be taken as input with `scanf` .

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Using `%c` will be an exception in such case .

Comment: @ameyCU Yes of course, but was this actually in question?

Answer (score 0):

You can have `scanf` read line by line. If only a new line char is entered (ie. user pressed enter) an empty line will appear that you can handle. Try this :

```
char input[1024];
while (scanf("%1023[^\n]\n", input) == 1) {
    if (input[0] == '\0') {
        // handle empty line
        continue;
    }
    // handle non-empty line
}
```

In this case input will always be null-terminated and will not contain `'\n'`. Note how `scanf` is only allowed to read as many chars as allowed by the size of the buffer minus null char at the end. Also `scanf` on success returns the number of variables it managed to scan. 1 in this case.

Comment: I don't think that's  what OP wants . He wants to call a function when only `'\n'` is entered . But with your code this wont happen .

Comment: @ameyCU you are probably right. I modified the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::basic_string::empty`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty) we can run the input in a loop and if the user just presses enter without entering any text we can detect that and call a function.  In this example I just end the loop is nothing is entered.

```
void no_input()
{
    std::cout << "You did not enter anything";
}

int main() {
    bool keep_going = true;
    while (keep_going)
    {
        std::string foo;
        std::cout << "Enter command: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, foo);
        if (foo.empty())
        {
            no_input();
            keep_going = false;
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://ideone.com/a9gPEm)</kbd>